# CardView inside RecyclerView scrolling vertically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating an android application which requires cardview inside recyclerview scrolling vertically. As in multiple cards scrolling vertically. But i cant get more than one card in one screen.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.How do i get cards scrolling adjacently?

MainActivity sets the recycler view layout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CardView cardView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        CustomAdapter adapter =new CustomAdapter(this);



        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager );
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    }
}
```

Card_layout is a linearlayout with a card layout holding a linear layout with three plain texts and one button.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:background="@color/card_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

main activity contains recyclerview. it is relative layout. Adapter class holds the cardview layout inside recyclerview

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
         />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @kashyap I want it scroll vertically just side by side. Right now, its one card on one screen

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in Root `View-Group` `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

  // only change this below line
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:background="@color/card_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


      //rest of the code here



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your xml code to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:background="@color/card_bg"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

using   android:layout_width="match_parent" its the problem

try the code I post